# Are there APIs to automate google smart home action integration?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-voice-actions

I am looking for ways to automate smart home action integration using APIs or CLIs, so that it will not be required to visit Google actions console to configure the integration.

I have tried out [gactions CLI](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions), but pushing manifest for smart home actions gives this error: "Actions project must specify at least one action in actions.yaml."
As my actions project is smart home action and not conversational action, custom actions are not applicable for my project.

As per documentation, actions API also seems to be applicable only to conversational action.

For Alexa smart home skill, I am able to use SMAPI SDK to push smart home skill manifest, is there some way using which I can push smart home action configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don’t provide the API or CLI to automate the Google Smart Home integration action. One needs to go to [Actions on Google](https://console.actions.google.com/) console to finish the setup